# Safely store textarea text in a hidden field using jQuery, then use the text later in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a modal which contains a textarea. When the user enters some text and then submits the modal, the modal closes and I want to store the text in a hidden field in the HTML.

1. What is the best way to safely escape all the text from the textarea, for storage in an HTML attribute? New line characters must be preserved.
2. If the user opens the modal again, how do I grab the text stored in the hidden field and put it back into the textarea as it was, complete with new line characters?
3. When the user submits the form, how do I normalise the text from the hidden field again so that it can be used or saved to the database in its original form, with new line characters?

I am open to alternative solutions for storing the textarea text with JvaScript to eventually get it to the PHP.

Comment: Why don't you just leave it into the textarea?

Comment: Because the textarea is in a modal. It is not part of the form that will get submitted to PHP. The textarea can also be cleared when the modal closes.

Comment: Append it to the form onsubmit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to safely escape all the text from the textarea, for storage in an HTML attribute? New line characters must be preserved.

Using `.val()` is the best option, it won't allow the textarea contents to break out of the hidden's value attribute. Using the native Javascript `.value` will also work and is safe, `.val()` is just a wrapper for that.

> If the user opens the modal again, how do I grab the text stored in the hidden field and put it back into the textarea as it was, complete with new line characters?

When the modal opens:

```
// #mytextarea = the textarea on the modal
// #myhidden = the hidden on the main page
$('#mytextarea').val($('#myhidden').val()); // set the modal textarea to the value of the hidden
```

When the modal closes or "saves":

```
$('#myhidden').val($('#mytextarea').val());
```

> When the user submits the form, how do I normalise the text from the hidden field again so that it can be used or saved to the database in its original form, with new line characters?

You don't need to do anything to preserve the new lines. Using a Prepared Statement just save the raw post value to the database. When you output the value on a page somewhere, you can convert the new lines to `<br />` by using PHP's `nl2br()`. Converting the new lines is only required if you're outputting to anything other than an input value. Also don't forget to run it through `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent XSS.

Comment: I had no idea `.val()` was that clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Here is the JSFiddle Check Out : http://jsfiddle.net/ganeshprabhu1994/THPVa/2/

HTML:

```
    <textarea id="ta" rows="10" columns="20">
 173-B,Perambalur Road,
 Near Water Tank,
    Thuraiyur-621010
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="cut" value="Cut" />
<input type="button" id="paste" value="Paste" />
<input type="hidden" id="hdn1" value="" />
```

Script:

```
$(function(){
$('#cut').click(function(){
    $('#hdn1').val($('#ta').val());
    $('#ta').val("");
});
$('#paste').click(function(){
    $('#ta').val($('#hdn1').val());
});
});
```